# how can I submit the value of an unchecked checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a user edit page with a set of user permissions. Each permission is basically a checkbox. If checked the user has the permission if unchecked the user does not have the permission. So if I want to remove a permission I would uncheck the box and vice versa to add a permission.

I got everything to work using a hidden input, but the problem that I am having is that it is submitting both the hidden input and the checkbox value. For example even if I don't make a change and click the update button, I get a message that reads:

```
Removed access from 1 permission levels
Added access to 1 permission levels
```

I will show you my code below. Something to keep in mind is that each input calls a different function.

Here is the inputs:

```
<ul class="list-group permission-summary-rows">
<?php //List of permission levels user is apart of
foreach ($permissionData as $v1) {
    if(isset($userPermission[$v1['id']])){
?>                              
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <?php echo $v1['name']; ?>
        <span class="pull-right">
            <input type="hidden" name="removePermission[<?php echo $v1['id'] ?>]" id="removePermission[<?php echo $v1['id'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $v1['id'] ?>" >
            <input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="switch" name="addPermission[<?php echo $v1['id'] ?>]" id="addPermission[<?php echo $v1['id'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $v1['id'] ?>" >
        </span>
    </li>                               
<?php
    }
}
?>
<?php //List of permission levels user is not apart of  
foreach ($permissionData as $v1) {
    if(!isset($userPermission[$v1['id']])){
?>                          
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <?php echo $v1['name']; ?>
        <span class="pull-right">                                               
            <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="switch" name="addPermission[<?php echo $v1['id'] ?>]" id="addPermission[<?php echo $v1['id'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $v1['id'] ?>" >                                         
        </span>
    </li>                           
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Here is the PHP:

```
//Remove permission level
    if(!empty($_POST['removePermission'])) {
        $remove = $_POST['removePermission'];
        if ($deletion_count = removePermission($remove, $userId)) {
            $successes[] = lang("ACCOUNT_PERMISSION_REMOVED", array ($deletion_count));
        } else {
            $errors[] = lang("SQL_ERROR");
        }
    }
    // Add permission level
    if(!empty($_POST['addPermission'])) {
        $add = $_POST['addPermission'];
        if ($addition_count = addPermission($add, $userId)) {
            $successes[] = lang("ACCOUNT_PERMISSION_ADDED", array ($addition_count));
        } else {
            $errors[] = lang("SQL_ERROR");
        }
    }
```

Even if I add the hidden input underneath the checkbox input I receive the same message. I know it has something to do with using different functions so can anyone guide me in the right direction? Should I use some JS code to find if it is checked or not?

Comment: Unchecked checkboxes and radio buttons are not submitted.

Comment: I know that is why i used the hidden input which works, but the problem is that it is submitting both the hidden and the checkbox. I only want it to submit if the box was unchecked or checked. For example by default the box is checked because the user has the permission so if they uncheck it I want it to submit only the hidden input.

Comment: You can just, after the submit, remove all the permissions from that user in the DB and then add the permissions that were submitted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use that trick... you must to name the same both arrays!

```
<input type="hidden" name="Permission[<?php echo $v1['id'] ?>]" id="removePermission[<?php echo $v1['id'] ?>]" value="0" >
<input type="checkbox" <?php echo ($v1['id']=='YES')?'checked':'' ?> data-toggle="switch" name="Permission[<?php echo $v1['id'] ?>]" id="AddPermission[<?php echo $v1['id'] ?>]" value="1" >
```

Take a look at "$v1['id']=='YES'" and use the correct comparison. Remember, name must be the same and a value of 0 will be disabled and 1 enabled.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

//EDIT:
This is the code I would use for this problem. Just overwrite all rules for the user in the DB. Only thing you have to know is the amount of rules (represented by the constant).

```
<html>
<body>

<?PHP

define("NUMBEROFINPUTS",5);

if(isset($_GET["permissions"])){
    $dbperms = array();
    foreach($_GET["permissions"] as $permission) {
        $dbperms[$permission] = 1;
    }
    //$dbperms: 0->Input is not set; 1-> Input is set
    for($i=0;$i<NUMBEROFINPUTS;$i++){
        if(isset($dbperms[$i])) {
            echo "Input ".$i." is set<br />";
        }
        else{
            echo "Input ".$i." is not set<br />";
        }
    }
}
else {
    echo '<form>';
    for($i = 0;$i<NUMBEROFINPUTS;$i++){
        echo 'Permission '.$i.': <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="'.$i.'" checked /><br />';
    }
    echo '<input type="submit" /></form>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope I could help.

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer for my most straight forward solution.

Comment: I am a little confused. Should I be replacing my code with yours? if so which part of my code do I replace?

Comment: Just put my code into an empty file and put it onto your test server (e.g. XAMPP). Open it up and you'll see what it does...

Answer (score 0):

Both the hidden input and the checkbox values are submitted because they're of different input types.

You don't need to hardcode checked explicitly. Write a php if loop to check if the user has permission and echo "checked" accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

use this in jQuery

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").attr("value");
```

well for get and do some with all unchecked checkbox you can collect it into array... and send it on submit to server

```
var aUnchecked = new Array();
$("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").each(fucntoin(){
    aUnchecked.push($(this).attr("name"));
}
```

Comment: Will this submit the value of all other inputs that are unchecked?